# Why won't Maven download jar files but does download plugins fine?

Tags: java, maven

Ok I'm moving my development environment from my laptop to my desktop.

I've got the exact same projects on both machines but when I try to run maven's update dependencies through eclipse on the desktop is just complains about "missing artefact" for every single dependency!?

I've checked the local repo on the desktop and sure enough, there are NO jars!? All the pom's are there but no jars!

I went back to the laptop, deleted from jars from the local repo on that machine and called the update dependencies again and bang, the jars download just fine, but the desktop can't seem to download any of the jars?

Both machines are on the same network/router so it can't be hardware firewall/proxy but is there some eclipse setting or windows firewall setting I'm totally forgetting about??

Lastly, I've been deleteing the repo on the desktop and using mvn -up clean install on the project, I notice that it downloads the PLUGIN jars just fine, but then continues to only download poms for any and all dependencies!?

My settings.xml is as follows (kind of a mashup of suggested repos);

```
  <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
<proxies></proxies>
<servers></servers>
<mirrors></mirrors>
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>standard-extra-repos</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>net.java.download</id>
                <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>org.apache</id>
                <url>http://maven.apache.org/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>org.codehaus.mojo</id>
                <url>http://mojo.codehaus.org/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>com.jboss.repository</id>
                <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release
                </id>
                <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository -
                    SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
                <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external
                </id>
                <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository -
                    External Bundle Releases</name>
                <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.release
                </id>
                <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository -
                    SpringSource Library Releases</name>
                <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.external
                </id>
                <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository -
                    External Library Releases</name>
                <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external
                </url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Make sure that you have the proper settings in your settings.xml file.

Comment: maven configuration is the same on both machines? (file settings.xml)

Comment: See edit to original question for settings.xml ... same on both machines, save for on laptop I have a <server> in that section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm not sure if this is a no brainer but I WAS using maven 3.0.1 on the desktop, I downloaded 2.2.1 again to match the laptop and BANG, dependency jars download just fine now! So much for "backwards compatible" maven 3!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the content of the downloaded POMs. Sometimes Maven try download them, even create them on the file system, but if you look at the content you'll find some server error code, maybe that can help..

Comment: pom file content looks fine, no errors or nothing, just normal xml poms

Comment: hmm, otherwise as most people says here, check your settings.xml, are they the same on both machine?

Comment: Try to run mvn clean install -X on your project, maybe the problem will come up in the logs

Comment: Seems to me both ApavenMaven and Codehause repo URL are not valid, that should be something like http://repository.codehaus.org/ http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ instead isn't it?

Comment: Ok, with that -X option I get a whole ton of exceptions similar to this; 
1) Could not transfer metadata eclipse:jdtcore/maven-metadata.xml from/to jaspersoft
2) Access denied to: http://www.jasperforge.org/maven2/jfree/jfreechart/maven-metadata.xml
3) No connector available to access repository java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1/) of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
4) Failed to collect dependencies for com.qualificationcheck:tQchckConnector:jar:2.1-r4 (system), javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1 (compile), etc etc

Comment: Look at the url of the repo I've told you, I really think their not right. Otherwise I tried to access manually the jfreechart repo url and in fact I got an access denied exception, guess their repo is dead, look at the pom of jfreechart it might declare a repository to use and you might be able to declare a mirror for it in your settings. But even so, JFreeChart is available on repo1.maven.org so put it in your settings as well. For the rest I don't really know, let me know how that goes

Comment: Oh, and have you tried to delete the repo on the machine where it seems to work and try to build again? If your settings are the same I'm pretty sure it will fail as well

Comment: I'll keep trying cheers, I also keep getting 13/01/11 13:14:07 GMT: 
Unable to update index for org.codehaus.mojo|http://repository.codehaus.org/
Unable to update index for org.apache|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Comment: This is madness! I deleted the repo on the laptop, unfortunately all the jars re-download just fine. I changed my settings.xml repos to the ones you mentioned, but it still says it can't update the indexes. I've looked in <workspace>/.metadata/.log and its complaining 403 forbidden on repo1.maven.org/maven2 and 404 not found on all the others, even when most of them if you paste the URL into a browser it loads a repo directory structure just fine! What the!?

Comment: Hmm are you sure your laptop doesn't have any java proxy settings set somewhere (-Dhttp.proxyHost etc) ? Otherwise you can try putting the mirror http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/ as well. you mentioned workspace, are you then doing all this through eclipse? Did you try the same directly from the command line just to make sure this is not some eclipse environment issue?

Comment: Oh and by the way you can try to specify your repository using the mirrors element of settings.xml instead of the profile thing, that's the way I usually do, I don't guarantee that's the proper way (since they suppposed to be mirrors!) but seems to work. Have a look at this page http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Comment: Hmm not sure if this is a no brainer but I WAS using maven 3.0.1 on the desktop, I downloaded 2.2.1 again to match the laptop and BANG, dependency jars download just fine now! So much for "backwards compatible" maven 3!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If it's not the proxy issue, then it might due to your network problem, which means your network can't connect to the repository center specified in your setting.xml.

**Try to change the repository center:**
In maven_home/conf/setting.xml, find **mirrors** tag, and replace your old/empty mirror with new mirror, then restart you eclipse.

Following is the mirror that works fine for me:

```
 <mirror>
       <id>ibiblio.org</id>
       <name>ibiblio Mirror of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</name>
       <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2</url>
       <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
       <!-- United States, North Carolina -->
 </mirror>
 <mirror> 
     <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id> 
     <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf> 
     <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name> 
     <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url> 
 </mirror>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Adding a duplicate server within the mirrors section solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your project to be portable across any machine, you cannot rely on the local settings.xml.  What I've commonly seen is actually building a local repo in a /target directory somewhere, and using it to run goals in a maven environment you generate at build time.  Convention seems to be src/main/it/settings.xml and src/main/it/local-repo.

I'm sure there's a maven plugin somewhere that will do it for you.